# Error installing Rethinkdb on Linux mint (libprotobuf7 not installable)

Tags: linux, rethinkdb, linux-mint

I am trying to install rethinkdb on Linux Mint 18 Serena, I add the repository but when i execute the code:

`sudo apt-get install rethinkdb`

it throws this error:

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this issue](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/6166) which is valid for Mint 18 Sarah, as Mint 18.1 Serena is based on xenial too, it should work :

```
echo "deb http://download.rethinkdb.com/apt xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rethinkdb.list
```

Then as specified in [redthinkdb installation instruction](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install/mint/) :

```
wget -qO- https://download.rethinkdb.com/apt/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rethinkdb
```

Looking at [xenial package](http://download.rethinkdb.com/apt/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/), it uses `libprotobuf9v5`, so you may have installed a wrong repository link :

```
Package: rethinkdb
Version: 2.3.1~0xenial
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: RethinkDB <packaging@rethinkdb.com>
Installed-Size: 38533
Pre-Depends: adduser (>= 3.40), procps (>= 3.2)
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.4), libprotobuf9v5, libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1d), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
```

Check `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/rethinkdb.list` file to make sure you have the `xenial` repo